# Error converting value "AAAAAAAAB9c=" to type 'System.Version'. Path 'version'

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, type-conversion, azure-mobile-services

Whenever I try to access my Azure Mobile Service table, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error converting value "AAAAAAAAB9k=" to type
>   'System.Version'. Path 'version', line 19, position 27.

This is the line where this error occurred:

```
await App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().InsertAsync(todoItem);
```

I don't actually need the version value in my table. This value is automatically generated by Azure. Is there a way to force ignore the version value?

This is the TodoItem definition:

```
 public class TodoItem
    {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
    public Version version { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }

    ... and so on...
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `TodoItem`?

Comment: Have you tried adding `[JsonIgnore]` to the `Version` property in the `TodoItem` class?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the definition. Thanks!

Comment: don't use `System.Version` use a string.

Comment: @BrianRogers No, I have not. How should I?

Comment: I don't think the error has to do with version.  The data not being de-serialized properly.  Definition of the 'TodoItem' in the Serializer has to be the same has in the deserializer.  This type error often occurs when the 'TodoItem' has been changed in the serializer and not changed in de-serializer.The other possibility is not all the data is being received.  The connection could be closing before all the data is read.The client should be the Mobile device which opens and closes the connections.  The Server should be a slave and only process commands/data that originate in the client.

Comment: @DanielA.White That fixed the problem! Not sure if this is a proper fix though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using `System.Version` for this purpose. `System.Version` is for numeric version values such as software releases that following this pattern: `w.x.y.z`. It looks like you are receiving a string that can't fit that, nor do I expect you to.

Answer (score 3):

Your TodoItem code is wrong.  It should be something like:

```
[Version]
public string Version {get; set;}
```

Here [Version] references VersionAttrbute that is located in the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices namespace.